# Is it possible to change the login shell on Google Secure LDAP?

Tags: ldap, g-suite

The [Google Secure LDAP
Schema](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9188164?hl=en) lists these
two attributes as having default values:

> - homeDirectory: The user’s POSIX home directory. Defaults to
>     “/home/< username>”.
> - loginShell: The user’s POSIX login shell. Defaults to “/bin/bash”.

Google Secure LDAP is read-only, going by
[this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9167101?hl=en) (emphasis
mine):

> #### PROTOCOL_ERROR (2)
>
> [...]
>
> - Returned when a request specifies an unsupported action.
>     Google supports **Abandon**, **Bind**, **Extended** (for
>     StartTLS), **Search**, and **Unbind**. *Unsupported actions
>     are: **Add, Compare, Del, Modify,** and **ModifyDn.***

This means that the usual ways of modifying login shells on LDAP (using
`chsh.ldap`, or writing an LDIF file and applying it using `ldapmodify`,
etc.) won't work (and they don't - I tried anyway).

I have gone through the various attributes I can modify for a user, and
I don't see an entry for either setting. While the default home
directory isn't a problem, users can be picky about their shells (I am
too).

Given this is a "default", it seems it should be possible to set a
non-default value. How can I do that?

Notes:

- I do have super-admin privileges (necessary for enabling and configuring LDAP in the first place)
- I posted this on [the G Suite Admin community forum](https://support.google.com/a/thread/9436638?hl=en) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I opened a ticket with Google since I needed this answer too. The answer is the users posixAccount with "posixAccounts[].systemId" set to empty string ("") and "posixAccounts[].primary" set to true will be the one seen in Google LDAPS. Update the settings using the [update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update) API. Request body for the update would be:

```
{
  "posixAccounts": [
    {
      "username": "youruser",
      "homeDirectory": "/home/youruser",
      "shell": "/bin/bash",
      "primary": true,
      "operatingSystemType": "unspecified",
      "systemId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I confirmed that the above is now seen with a ldapsearch on the same user.